# Looking for help to use Google Cloud HSM with jarsigner to sign jar files

Tags: jarsigner, jar-signing

I need to sign jar files using Google Cloud HSM. The standard tool for signing jar files that comes with the JDK is `jarsigner`. I see that **AWS** Cloud HSM has documentation on using AWS Cloud HSM with jarsigner to sign jar files.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudhsm/latest/userguide/keystore-third-party-tools.html

However, I could not find any documentation directly addressing how to use **Google** Cloud HSM with jarsigner to sign jar files. If there is no native support for this in Google Cloud HSM, what would be required to make jarsigner work with Google Cloud HSM to do the jar signing? Any pointers are welcome.

Comment: You'll need to implement a custom [JCA Provider](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/security/index.html) that communicates with Cloud HSM to do the signing. You won't need to implement everything, but probably a `KeyStoreSpi` and `SignatureSpi`.

Comment: Hi Ajoy. Did you find any solution for this case? I'm also stuck with this problem

Comment: @Augusto, Do you have any example about how to implement this provider ?

Comment: @CarlosSpohr, I don't. It might be worth searching the internet. Or give it a try with ChatGPT, I've had a lot of success using it for this kind of tasks to provide the scaffolding of a solution.

Answer (score 1):

[Jsign](https://ebourg.github.io/jsign/) provides a JCA provider that can be used with jarsigner to sign with a Google Cloud HSM key (disclaimer: I'm the author of this project).

The syntax looks like this:

```
jarsigner -J-cp -Jjsign-5.1-SNAPSHOT.jar -J--add-modules -Jjava.sql \
           -providerClass net.jsign.jca.JsignJcaProvider \
           -providerArg projects/first-rain-123/locations/global/keyRings/mykeyring \
           -keystore NONE \
           -storetype GOOGLECLOUD \
           -storepass <api-access-token> \
           -certchain certificate-chain.pem \
           application.jar <keyname>
```

Comment: Yes, it's works like a charm! Thank you